# Recommendations for Tea/Fruity/Sweet beers?

Tags: recommendations, specialty-beers

I mainly drink ciders and sometimes I find a beer that I can tolerate the taste, even if I don't enjoy it. Something like Yuengling or Stella (not the cider). Recently I tried [Sea Dogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_Dog_Brewing_Company) Tea Beer which hasn't hit the stores as far as I know. From what a bartender has told me, it is because it is very expensive to brew, so at the moment I'm drinking things like Blood Orange/Strawberry Mike Hards, Strawberry-Lime Rekorderlig, most Sour beers, and other ciders like Angry Orchard.

I'd like to find something new that fits my taste buds with a sweet or sour after taste that is light in color (like pale ales and such). I'm not a big alcohol buff like my boyfriend, but I learned this much just from going to tap houses and tasting rooms.

Comment: This depends quite a bit on the region you're from and the drinks you have available to you, but a pretty common, widespread and popular sweet beer is 'Fruli' strawberry beer.

Answer (score 5):

If you like sour beers and fruit flavors, try [lambics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambic).  I've known several people who "don't drink beer" who like this style.

A lambic is a Belgian style, light in color and usually in alcohol level, that is fermented with wild yeasts and (usually) combined with fruit.  It has a sour element to the taste, which is most notable with the non-fruit variety (*gueuze*).

Comment: Framboise? Those are the main sour beers myself and boyfriend drink, however the ones we've tried were 12+ in alcohol level. We also tried some sour mead too that was 13.5, was a bit too sour for my taste to have in one sitting but there are some I like.

Comment: Framboise is one type of lambic (raspberry). The [one I'm familiar with](http://www.merchantduvin.com/brew-lindemans-framboise-lambic.php) is more like 3% alcohol, though, not 13.  (This is true of the Lindemans lambics in general.)  The peach (Peche) is less sweet than the Framboise, and cherry (Kriek) is more sweet as I recall.  (I didn't care for it so I've only had it once, a while ago.)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like the [Grapefruit radler](http://www.treebeer.com/grapefruit-radler/). I find it very nice on a hot summer day and you can mix it with other juices if you are not into grapefruit.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, and a similar style to keep an eye out for is a shandy.

Answer (score 0):

Anderson Valley is the de facto source of sour beers in my area. Their Blood Orange Gose and Briney Melon Gose are fairly refreshing. https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/193/184814/

21st Amendment Brewing also has a watermelon flavored wheat that is fairly popular around here. It's definitely a "love it or hate it" item. https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/735/4202/

If you are looking for something with a little more of a beer kick, fruit flavored IPA's are a nice option. Flying Dog has a good one: https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/68/92018/

Answer (score 0):

I would add one more suggestion from Italy: the Belgian Ale [**Birra Kuka Rosa**](https://www.birrakuka.it/prodotto/rosa-0-50l/).

Translating some excerpts from the webpage linked above:

> From the reinterpretation of an ancient Belgian recipe still used in the Gent area, which involves the use of berries during malting, a unique aroma is obtained [...] The smell is fragrant, with clear notes of raspberries and red fruits which however do not cover the hints of hops and malt. The taste features notes of red fruit and spices.

Then, once again, I am so surprised that noone in years mentioned the specialties by the Swedish [**Brewski**](https://www.1001birre.it/brewski), brewed with cherries or berries or pineapple or mango...and - well - probably many other fruits!!

Answer (score -1):

Tame beers with low hops and malts would be a great transition, look for fruity beers low in IBU. I'd suggest something like a Raspberry Wheat, which will be light and refreshing, with a sweet berry finish.